# Solve $\int_a^\infty y^{-2n+1} dy$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

for some parameter $a < \infty$ and $n \ge 1$ I calculate the following integral as follows

$$
\int_a^\infty y^{-2n+1} dy = \left[ \frac{y^{-2(n-1)}}{-2(n-1)} \right]_a^\infty = \frac{a^{-2(n-1)}}{2(n-1)}
$$

Is this correct? I'm not sure if I need to treat $n=1$ and $n>1$ separately.

Comment: Yes, for n=1, the integral is different, as $$\int x^{-1}dx=\ln{x}$$

Comment: @s5s You also need to deal separately with $a>0$ and $a \leq 0$.

Answer (score 1):

$\int_a^\infty y^{-2n+1} dy$

- $(n > 1) \wedge (a > 0): \left[ \frac{y^{-2(n-1)}}{-2(n-1)} \right]_a^\infty = \frac{a^{-2(n-1)}}{2(n-1)} $
- $¬ \left[(n > 1) \wedge (a > 0)\right] = (n \leq 1) \vee (a \leq 0): \infty$

Comment: What if $a \leq 0$?

Comment: Well, it seems not a problem here, except $a = 0$.

Comment: If $a <0$ you still have a problem because the function to be integrated is not bounded near $y=0$.

Answer (score 1):

If $a>0$, as it was already mentioned, the integral converges when $n>1$ and, in that case
$$
\int_a^{+\infty} y^{-2n+1} dy = \left[\frac{y^{-2n+2}}{-2n+2}\right]_a^{+\infty}=\frac{a^{-2n+2}}{2n-2}
$$

If $a \leq 0$, the integral becomes improper also for $y=0$ and the convergence would require that $2n-1 < 1$, which does not allow the convergence of the integral in the set $[a, +\infty[$.